# Updating specific item in realtime database using recycler view

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Actually I want to update a specific item in recycler view using firebase realtime database. I have created a schema and included it in my java file.
But I am not able to update any item present in my firebase realtime database which has been saved using add item button.

firstly, I tried to get the particular item id but it always returns random key but not the key of the item when clicked is selected.
I only want to update productdescription and product rate in an existing record of current product item selected.

UpdateActivity.java

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Products"); 
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
               .child("Products");
```

**Products is the table name in firebase**

```
private void update_item_actual() {
  String productdescription = updateproductdescription.getText()
                              .toString();
    String productrate = updateproductrate.getText().toString();

    String key = mDatabaseRef.child("Products").push().getKey();

    //I need to perform update here
}
```

StorageSchema
    package Model;

```
public class StorageSchema {


    private String productdescription;
    private int rate;
    private int position;
    private String key;


    public StorageSchema(){
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public StorageSchema(int position){
        this.position=position;
    }

    public StorageSchema(String productdescription, int rate){
        if(productdescription.trim().equals("")){
            productdescription = "No Name";
        }
        this.productdescription = productdescription;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getProductdescription() {
        return productdescription;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code `String key = mDatabaseRef.child("Products").push().getKey();` will generate a new unique ID. If you want to update an existing product, you will instead need to know the key of that existing product.

There are two ways to know the key of the product you want to update:

1. You've passed it along your app from the moment when you loaded the data.
2. You have some other value that allows you to perform a query on the database to look up the key.

The first option is the most common, as you'll typically be loading the data from the database already, and can "simply" pass the `DataSnapshot.getKey()` along when you're already loading `DataSnapshot.getValue()`.

Once you have the key of the product/child node, you can update its data with:

```
private void update_item_actual() {
  String productdescription = updateproductdescription.getText()
                              .toString();
  String productrate = updateproductrate.getText().toString();

  String key = "-Lckhadu10a9813"; // TODO: use the key you passed along or looked up

  Map<String, Value> values = new HashMap<>();
  values.put("productdescription", productdescription);
  values.put("rate", productrate);

  mDatabaseRef.child(key).updateChildren(values);
}
```